# Using autolayout to position view at (c + (x * superview.width))

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I'm a bit confused on autolayout at the moment. I have a `UITableViewCell` in a .xib file:

[image: Table view cell]

My goal is to get a set of vertical lines equally spaced horizontally on the cell, starting from where the first line is (`x = 74`).

I have been trying a large combination of autolayout constraints, but I can't seem to get it right. The constraints that have gotten me the closest are as follows:

[image: Constraints attempt 1]

However, the `multiplier` has me thoroughly confused. In the first screenshot, the `multiplier`s are `6`, `2`, and `1` (from left to right), which doesn't make much sense to me considering the placement of the views.

The end goal is to essentially get each line positioned at: `(c + (x * superview.width))`where `c` is `74` in this case and `x` is the `multiplier`.

Can somebody please give me some pointers here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will probably find things easier if you use spacer views. Use as many as there are gaps between vertical lines. Constrain their widths to be equal. Constrain the horizontal spacing such that they run in sequence [line][spacer][line]….

However, to address the question that you asked: select the pop-up menu for First Item (reads Superview.Center X in your screenshot) and tell Xcode to swap the first and second items. The multiplier applies to the second item's attribute.

The general form for a constraint is:

```
firstItem.firstAttribute == secondItem.secondAttribute * multiplier + constant
```

(The relation could be `<=` or `>=`, too.)

Your screenshot translates to:

```
Superview.Center X == Image View.Center X * 6 + 69
```

You are multiplying the image view's center X coordinate, which doesn't make sense given the goal you described. You presumably want something like:

```
Image View.Center X == Superview.Width * 1/3 + 69
```

The problem is that you're never going to find a multiplier that works for all devices/orientation (with different widths) if "works" is defined as "vertical lines equally spaced horizontally".  To do so, you would need:

```
Image View.Center X == (Superview.Width - 69) * 1/3 + 69
```

That is, you would want to multiply by the remainder of the width after subtracting your starting point.

You could embed the lines in a subview, in which case you wouldn't need the 69 point starting value.

Answer (score 0):

At long last, I found a solution, which I have detailed below:

1. Control-drag from the subview to the superview and create a `Trailing Space to Container` constraint
2. Double click on the constraint in the sidebar
3. Change the `Second Item` to `<subview>.Center X`
4. Reverse the first and second item
5. Change the `constant` to `-74`
6. Change the `multiplier` to multiples of `0.14`, starting from the left

I ended up with this constraint:

[image: Screenshot]